# floating button goes to right when transelating to arabic

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have small issue on my floating button , the floating button its on the buttom right. When I click to english language it appears the same position.

Now my point is , how to let the floating button stay at the same place when translating to arabic, becoz when I click to arabic language, the items inside the floating button goes to left of the screen.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dd"
    tools:context="com.egov.SharjahPoliceSmartApp.activity.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            layout="@layout/footer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ParentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:background="@drawable/dash_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/LogoText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RecycleView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/DimLayout"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blackTransparent"
             />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Dashboard"
            style="@style/fab_parent"

            android:layout_marginBottom="160dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_Dashboard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt"
                android:src="@drawable/img_2"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:duplicateParentState="false"
                style="@style/fab_style_txt"
                android:text="@string/dashboard" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Library"
            style="@style/fab_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="110dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_Library"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt2"
                android:src="@drawable/img_1"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"

                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:duplicateParentState="false"
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                style="@style/fab_style_txt"
                android:text="@string/library" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Store"
            style="@style/fab_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_Store"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt3"
                android:src="@drawable/img_3"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                style="@style/fab_style_txt"
                android:text="@string/store" />
        </RelativeLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: *items inside the floating button* what items?

Comment: like texts from example

Comment: You don't have text inside the fab only image

Comment: yah image but how show i display it on right buttom eaither its arabic or english,

Comment: which english its working fine, but with arabic , the images goes to left side. plz help to fix

Comment: The image in a fab is always in the center of the fab.

Comment: ok but why when its english working fine , with arabic its goes to left

Comment: You have 3 fabs. What about the other 2?

Comment: all the same , when its english its working find.

Comment: @MohamedHassanYousifBinyousi you can send image how it is look in arabic ?

Comment: but when click button to transleate to arabic , all the fabs goes to left

Comment: you can use `android:layoutDirection="ltr" `but i need to see the problem...

Comment: is the same problem i tried above code

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

put all fav buttons in RelativeLayout and set android:layoutDirection="ltr" :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"/>
   <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Dashboard"
            style="@style/fab_parent"

            android:layout_marginBottom="160dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_Dashboard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt"
                android:src="@drawable/img_2"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:duplicateParentState="false"
                style="@style/fab_style_txt"
                android:text="@string/dashboard" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Library"
            style="@style/fab_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="110dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_Library"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt2"
                android:src="@drawable/img_1"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"

                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:duplicateParentState="false"
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                style="@style/fab_style_txt"
                android:text="@string/library" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Store"
            style="@style/fab_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_Store"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt3"
                android:src="@drawable/img_3"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                style="@style/fab_style_txt"
                android:text="@string/store" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```